# Is there a definiton of "the degree of connectivity of a set"?

Tags: general-topology

I wonder whether there is a definition that quantitatively describes the degree of connectivity of a set?

More specifically, in general topology, there is seemingly only a qualitative definition saying that whether a set is *connected* or not. But a connected set may be close to be disconnected, while another may not.

If there isn't such a definition, I wonder why it's not necessary or can't be defined?

p.s. I noticed that in Graph theory, there is a basic concept called *connectivity*, defined as

> the minimum number of elements (nodes or edges) that need to be
> removed to separate the remaining nodes into two or more isolated
> subgraphs.

I think this concept is somehow a discrete-version counterpart of what I want.

Thanks!

Comment: The real question is: how such thing is useful? At the end of the day we only work on things that are useful. Either in the real world, or to solve other mathematical problems. And such "degree of connectivity" is just not useful. Not at the moment anyway. But hey, what exactly stops you from taking care of such problem? Who knows, maybe in the future it will be of use.

Comment: @freakish Thx! I had the sense that it must be unnecessary (at the moment) so that people didn't define it. Actually I'm dealing with a problem relating more tightly to engineering. I guess I need to define such a thing on my own. Anyway, still appreciating your reply!

Comment: By analogy with graphs you can define the minimal cardinality of a finite subset separating your topological space.